# How to control a non-React component (BokehJS) in React?

Tags: reactjs, bokeh, bokehjs

**Backstory**
I want to include a BokehJS plot in my React component. The process for this is to render `<div id="my_plot_id" className="bk-root"/>` and call `window.Bokeh.embed.embed_item(plotData, 'my_plot_id')` which injects needed HTML into the DOM.

Because I want to control the BokehJS plot using the React component's state (i.e replace the plot with new generated plot data), I don't want to just call `embed_item()` in `componentDidMount()`. I've instead placed `embed_item()` in `render()` and added some code to remove child nodes of the container div prior to this call.

**Problem**
My React component renders 3 times on page load and although by the final render I have only one plot displayed, there is a brief moment (I think between the 2nd and 3rd/final render) where I see two plots.

**Code**

```
render()
  {
    let plotNode = document.getElementById('my_plot_id');    
    console.log(plotNode && plotNode.childElementCount);

    while (plotNode && plotNode.firstChild) {
      //remove any children
      plotNode.removeChild(plotNode.firstChild);
    }

    const { plotData } = this.state;
    window.Bokeh.embed.embed_item(plotData, 'my_plot_id');

    return(
      <div id="my_plot_id" className="bk-root"/>
    )
  }
```

In console I see:

> null
>  
>   0
>  
>   2

**Question**
So it seems `embed_item` executes twice before the `my_plot_id` children are correctly detected.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it? While the triple render may not be performance optimized I believe my component should be able to re-render as often as it needs to (within reason) without visual glitching like this, so I haven't focused my thought on ways to prevent re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Interaction with DOM elements should **never** happen inside the `render` method. You should initiate the library on the element using the lifecycle method `componentDidMount`, update it based on props using `componentDidUpdate` and destroy it using `componentWillUnmount`.

The [official React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) has an example using jQuery which shows you the gist of how to handle other dom libraries.

Answer (score 0):

At start `plotNode` is unable to reach `'my_plot_id'`.

You can render `null` at start, when `plotData` is unavailable.

You can use `componentDidUpdate()`.

In this case I would try `shouldComponentUpdate()` - update DOM node and return `false` to avoid rerendering.